# HTMLCollection Index Change Not Reflected in Variables After .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, htmlcollection

I have a stack of `div`s that I have set up in a carousel fashion. Using JQuery I `.append()` or `.prepend()` a `div` to the top or bottom of the stack when "next" or "previous" buttons are clicked. The top/visible `div` is the "active" `div` that corresponds to an `<iframe>` of a similarly named `id` attribute. When a `div` becomes "active" after clicking a next/previous button, I want my Javascript to pull the `src` attribute value from the corresponding `<iframe>` so I can use it elsewhere in my program.

The problem I'm having is that when I click the previous or next buttons, the `div`s reorder perfectly, but the corresponding variables do not reflect the new "active" `div`. For example, `activeAlbumID` remains `discovery-sounds` when it should be `space-sounds` after a button click.

Here's my `<html>`:

```html
<div id='stack'>
  <div class="album" id="space-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="vintage-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="rocket-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="mercury-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="kennedy-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="apollo-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="shuttle-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="discovery-sounds"></div>
</div>

<iframe id="space-widget" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/558303876"></iframe>
<iframe id="vintage-widget" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/270811947"></iframe>
<iframe id="rocket-widget" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/55326279"></iframe>
<iframe id="mercury-widget" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/55323699"></iframe>
<iframe id="kennedy-widget" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/55323646"></iframe>
<iframe id="apollo-widget" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/55323442"></iframe>
<iframe id="shuttle-widget" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/55323280"></iframe>
<iframe id="discovery-widget" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/55322828"></iframe>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```js
$(window).bind("load", function() {

  var albums = document.getElementsByClassName('album');
  var playlists = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
  var activeAlbum = albums[albums.length - 1];
  var activeAlbumID = activeAlbum.id;
  var activeAlbumPre = activeAlbumID.split('-');
  var activePlaylist = activeAlbumPre[0] + '-widget';
  var widgetSRC = $('#' + activePlaylist).attr('src');
  
  $('i:nth-child(1), i:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
    //Click previous button
    if (this.id == 'prev'){
      //Pull out album from bottom of stack
      $(albums[0]).addClass('animate-album');
      //Wait for animation to finish
      $(albums[0]).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
        //Set explicit element margin
        $(albums[0]).css('margin-left', '400px');
        //Remove animation styles/margin so doesn't re-fire on append
        $(albums[0]).removeClass('animate-album');
        //Put bottom album on top
        $('#stack').append(albums[0]);
        //Force browser to calculate margin value
        $(albums[albums.length - 1]).css('margin-left');
        //Transition album back to original position
        $(albums[albums.length - 1]).css('margin-left', '0px');
      });
    }
    else{
      //Push album to bottom of stack
      $(albums[albums.length - 1]).addClass('animate-album');
      //Wait for animation to finish
      $(albums[albums.length - 1]).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
        //Set explicit element margin
        $(albums[albums.length - 1]).css('margin-left', '400px');
        //Remove animation styles/margin so doesn't re-fire on prepend
        $(albums[albums.length - 1]).removeClass('animate-album');
        //Put top album on bottom
        $('#stack').prepend($(albums[albums.length - 1]));
        //Force browser to calculate margin value
        $(albums[0]).css('margin-left');
        //Transition album back to original position
        $(albums[0]).css('margin-left', '0px');
      });
    }
  });
 });
```

So for instance, when I click the "previous" button, `discovery-sounds` gets pushed to the bottom of the stack and `space-sounds` to the top and becomes visible, this works great:

```html
<div id='stack'>
  <div class="album" id="discovery-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="vintage-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="rocket-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="mercury-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="kennedy-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="apollo-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="shuttle-sounds"></div>
  <div class="album" id="space-sounds"></div>
</div>
```

Printing `albums` to the console produces the updated and correct stack index, but all variables following produce the original "active" value:

```js
//Expected
console.log(activeAlbum); //<div class="album" id="space-sounds"></div>
console.log(activeAlbumID); //spsce-sounds

//Actual
console.log(activeAlbum); //<div class="album" id="discovery-sounds"></div>
console.log(activeAlbumID); //discovery-sounds
```

Comment: On click, you append or prepend elements. But all the `var` you have are defined on `load`... And do not change after that. That's the issue. Script coding is like talking to an idiot. You have to explicitly define every thing. Do not assume it will get the idea.

Comment: Yes, all the variables are defined on 'load', but the 'albums' node is updated with a button click. This is reflected when I print  to console     console.log(album[7]). Returns 'space-sounds' as it should. Why is 'albums' updated and nothing after? I guess I'm misunderstanding how javascript updates variables.

Comment: Apologies for the comment without code formatting, SO locked me out of editing after 5 minutes: `console.log(album[7])` `space-sounds` `albums`

Comment: I suppose that you did not post all the markup... Since I can't find no `<i id="prev">`... Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wxJGmN?editors=1011) with what's posted. Can you fork and complete it?

Comment: Here's [my fork](https://codepen.io/codemensch/pen/ejvBep?editors=1111). Click on the left "previous" arrow to see the second set of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before the end of the `animationend` handlers, just "renew" the elements collection that "move"... Due to the append/prepend in DOM.

```
// Renew the albums collection.
albums = document.getElementsByClassName('album');
activeAlbum = albums[albums.length - 1];
activeAlbumID = activeAlbum.id;
```

[Updated forked CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qyrRdx?editors=1011)

Comment: This is the answer, except I needed to refresh all relevant variables in order to obtain updated `activePlaylist` and `widgetSRC`. Updated [Codepen](https://codepen.io/codemensch/pen/ejvBep?editors=1111). Thank you! I'm still curious as to why `albums` reflected the update but no other variables did. Any thoughts?